# Using the pattern of a pattern rule in a function with GNU make

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

I'd like to use a pattern rule for compiling classes that depend on other classes. For each class I define the classes it depends on and the header file. When compiling a specifc class I'd like to add every header file of every class to the prerequisites like this:

```
# Class 1
C1 = C1
C1_H = C1.hpp
C1_T =
C1_O = C1.o

# Class 2, depending on class 1
C2 = C2 $(C1)
C2_H = C2.hpp
C2_T = 
C2_O = C2.o

.SECONDEXPANSION:

# pattern rule. Want to read the C%_H variable of every class this depends on
C%.o : C%.hpp C%.cpp $(foreach var,$$(C%),$($(var)_H))
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
```

The foreach function doesn't work here, as the expansion of '%' occurs after the function expansion. Is there a way to still do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In C++, you don't compile _classes_, you compile _files_.

Comment: Have a look at the -M option of gcc, see http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html for instance.

Comment: @sbi, Deve: One way to amend that impedance mismatch ("In C++, you don't compile classes, you compile *files*") is by having only one class per file.  Whether this is a good idea or not is up to you and your experimentation (I imagine it might make compiling somewhat slower?).  But, it works for Java :)

Comment: @Merlyn: It works for Java because Java has only classes. If you put one class per file, where would you put `main()`?

Comment: @sbi: What, you want to *run* your program? :)  You're right, that suggestion won't work

Answer (score 2):

1) Here's a way to do what you're asking (more or less):

```
C1_HEADERS = C1.hpp
C1.o: $(C1_HEADERS)

C2_HEADERS = C2.hpp $(C1_HEADERS)
C2.o: $(C2_HEADERS)

# and so on
```

It may be possible to replace those second lines (`Cn.o: $(Cn_HEADERS)`) with a function call or something, but I really don't think it's worth the effort.

2) Here's one way in which your plan is overkill:

```
// C1.hpp
#include "A.hpp"
...


// C1.cpp
#include "C1.hpp"
#include "B.cpp"
...
```

So `C1.o` depends on `B.hpp`, but `C2.o` doesn't.

3) Here's a better way to handle these dependencies: [Advanced Auti-Dependency Generation](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html).

Comment: First of all, my minimal example seems to be an overkill, yes. But the real case is much more complex due to the use of templates. Your example would surely work for the simple case but not for what I'm planning to do. When compiling and linking I have to differentiate between class files and template files. I want to do that when defining the dependencies and not when defining the rules. Thanks for the hint in 3), I'll check it out.